# React Router Match URL contains filename and query parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We had old react web application which had two pages.
test1.html 
test.html
We access like http://domain/test1.html?somequeryparams & http://domain/test2.html?somequeryparams

Now we implementing react routing for code splitting,
So far I have created router like this

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'

import Loadable from 'react-loadable'
import Loading from './loading'

const Home = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./home' /* webpackChunkName: 'home' */),
    loading: Loading,
})

const PageOne = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./pageOne.js' /* webpackChunkName: 'pageOne' */),
    loading: Loading,
})

const PageTwo = Loadable({

    loader: () => import('./pageTwo.js' /* webpackChunkName: 'pageTwo' */),
    loading: Loading,
})

const TestComponent = Loadable({
    loader: () => import ('./TestComponenet.jsx' /* webpackChunkName: 'test' */),
    loading: Loading,
});
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/pageOne">Page One</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/pageTwo">Page Two</Link></li>
                <li><a href="/test.html?foo=1&a=b">Page Test Comp</a></li>
            </ul>

            <hr/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/pageOne" component={PageOne}/>
                <Route exact path="/pageTwo" component={PageTwo}/>
                <Route path="/test.html" component={TestComponent}/>

            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
)
```

All components print sample html string. But when I try to route for test.html it fails with `Cannot GET /test.html` 404 Page not found.

we need to keep this url same as its legacy url are like this.
If I change `<a href="/test.html?foo=1&a=b">Page Test Comp</a>` to `<Link to="/test.html?foo=1&a=b">Page Test Comp</Link>`
but if I refresh page it gives `404` error.

For webpack-dev server even I have added :

```
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        rewrites: [
            {from: /.*test.html.*$/, to: 'index.html'}
        ]
    },
    index: 'index.html'
},
```

How should we match this route? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle / codesandbox around it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Routes declared via **BrowserRouter** also needs to be implemented  on the Server side as well.

For E.g - Using BrowserRouter, If you have a route like this -

```
<Route exact path="/test.html" component={TestComponent}/>
```

And when you hit the direct URL - http://localhost/test.html directly, the hosting server will check for the existence of the file test.html and if not found, displays the following error message-

```
Cannot GET /test.html
```

> If I change [Page Test Comp](/test.html?foo=1&a=b) to Page Test Comp but if I refresh page it gives 404 error.

when you use anchor tag, the browser issues a new request to the hosting server to GET test.html, which is not there and hence the 404 not found error.
When using ***link*** tag the Browser router handles it internally and only on page refresh, the browser issues a new request to the server asking for test.html - which gives the 404, as the page test.html do not exists on the hosting server.

So to answer your question, there are two ways to workaround the problem -

1. Change route declaration from /test.html to /test
   OR
2. have an test.html which has the reference to the generated web chunk test.js